# Can I disable custom validation rules in Cerberus?

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

I have some custom validation rules I'm using for somewhat complex validation of in Cerberus (following http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/customize.html).

They work fine, but occasionally when testing or working with files I know are correct I would like to skip these additional rules to save time (some involve web lookups, etc.).

Is there a built-in or recommended way of doing this?

Background: I originally tried adding a `_skip_validation` member attribute, with member functions `disable_validation()` and `enable_validation()` to set this as `True` or `False`. Then, in my `_validate_isvalid...` functions, I have an `if` statement for that attribute. However, it seems that children of the validator do not retain this attribute, and so the validator only skips these rules for top-level keys.

Comment: Maybe a custom validator using an implementation of one of the `*-of-rules` http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#of-rules ?

Comment: @dizzyf I would have to look into it more, but my initial feeling is that I want this to be done in the calling code, rather than the file(s) that are being validated. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, though.

Comment: When you say you want it to be done in the calling code, what do you mean? Can you add some example code for what you've tried / are trying to do?